# Using the rugarch package when sample size is small

Tags: r, time-series

I have a question about the `rugarch` package.

My sample size is 43 and I have a problem to model a garch whose mean equation includes an exogenous model; otherwise my mean equation is linear regression, that is, $y_i=a+bx_i+e_i$ that $i=1, \ldots, 43$ and $e_i$ follow a $\text{garch}(1,1)$. But when I run it simultaneously R says `you need at least 100 points`. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I don't know this package, but presumably the implication is not that you are asking something impossible, but that trying to fit this process with a small data set is dubious. Other than finding more data, your options appear to be cloning and editing the code so that you are not thrown out; or finding alternative software that does not work like that. However, you would be ignoring the advice of the programmer.

Comment: @saeed I also forgot: You may want to ask questions about rugarch and garch on quantitative finance beta: http://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @saeed one further note: If you want to know, how to implement the EWMA with R, have a look at my answer to this question: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7988/compute-a-time-series-of-daily-volatilities-in-r/7990#7990 There, I give one possibility to implement the EWMA with using R.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good [answer](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/quot-ugarchfit-quot-function-of-quot-rugarch-quot-package-needs-at-least-100-data-points-td4645609.html). It is an answer of the package developer to this type of question.

With less than 100 data points, you will probably not get a good result. Or it even does not converge.

The solutions mentioned in the link are as follows:

1. Use  bayesGARCH
2. If you are interested in the volatility forecast, the point estimates of the GARCH parameters are not necessarily important, so you can still get good volatility forecasts. The solution would be therefore to take the EWMA (special GARCH), this is what the  riskMetrics approach does. (you can use an EWMA implementation, so you don't get throwed out by an error message).